# "Quel(le)" vs "qu'est-ce que" in a specific case

Tags: grammaire

> *Quel est le cas maintenant?*

I know this is the right way to say it, however, would it be wrong if I put :

> *Qu'est-ce que le cas maintenant?*

I know they both mean 'what' literally, I'm just curious about the ways we use them. Does *qu'est-ce que* need *est* after it to make this work?

Comment: Your second sentence is just not correct...

Comment: Could you explain why?

Comment: To be completely honest, I would have a hard time relating to grammatical rules, some others here are much more "technical" than me on that :-) If I had been able to make a detailed answer, I would have done it.

Comment: "Qu'est-ce que le cas maintenant" is not correct, and has to be expressed with "quel". See the definition and use of "quel". "Qu'est-ce que..." would imply that you define something.

Comment: Hi! What are you trying to say with _quel est le cas maintenant?_ ? What _cas_ is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both sentences are grammatically correct but there is an issue with *cas* which is odd here and make them unidiomatic.

If we replace it with *choix* which works better, we have:

> *Quel est le choix maintenant ?*

which is correct and means:

> What is the choice now?

and

> *[Qu'est-ce](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/qu%E2%80%99est-ce) que le choix maintenant ?*

which is still correct but unlikely to be used as it means:

> *Qu'est-ce, le choix, maintenant ?*

which translates to:

> What is "choice" now?

i.e.

> How would you define "choice" now?

while I guess the expected meaning is *What's the choice now?*.

Note: ***Qu'est-ce que le...*** is usually replaced nowadays by ***qu'est-ce que c'est que le...*** or in spoken French by ***c'est quoi le...*** The latter can be used to mean either "what's the.." and "what means..."

Comment: Je dirais plutôt *Qu'est-ce que le choix est maintenant ?*. Mais je préfère de beaucoup la première possibilité

Comment: @Damien Ce deuxième *est* est le plus souvent omis dans ce style de tournure. *Qu'est-ce que le Tiers-État ?*, *Qu'est-ce que le travail ?*, etc.

Comment: Avec cette tournure, sans verbe, le sens est différent, comme tu l'indiques d'ailleurs dans ta réponse

Comment: I really don't think that "Qu'est-ce que le cas maintenant?" is grammatically correct. "qu'est-ce que le"-> quel. "Qu'est-ce que le choix est maintenant" -> grammatically incorrect. I suggest you send the sentences to the Académie, because all I could say is only me. But it seems really incorrect.

Comment: @Quidam No grammatical rule is broken in *Qu'est-ce que le cas maintenant ?*. However, the sentence is unlikely to mean what the OP expects and doesn't make much sense anyway because *qu'est-ce que le* is a literary form that expects a substantive to be explained but *le cas* doesn't looks like this. There are well known sentences using that pattern like the ones I already quoted in a previous comment.

Comment: @Quidam and *qu'est-ce que le choix est maintenant ?* is certainly correct too, being a long, explicit  form of *qu'est-ce que c'est maintenant ?*.

Comment: It still not grammatically correct, we should use "quel est le choix maintenant", qu'est-ce que is used for definition. Also used to ask something but with a verb. Qu'est-ce que tu dis? But qu'est-ce que + noun is a definition.

Comment: If you say for instance "Qu'est-ce que le mode de vie des inuits", you ask for a definition, it's different from "quel", in "Quel est leur mode de vie". Qu'est-ce que and quel are not interchangeable.

Comment: If you ask, it's part of FLE basic grammar. Quel always modifies a noun (and it's the pronoun to use when it's a noun), and qu'est-ce modifies a phrase with verb. When used with a noun, it's not the same meaning.

Comment: What I gathered from this is that qu'est-ce que, before a noun, makes it a question about the definition of the word, instead of the intended question, which would be with quel(le). I apologise if my sentence doesn't make much sense in its context in the first place.

Comment: @Quidam You are confusing grammar and meaning (i.e. *correct* and *right*). The fact for a sentence to properly communicate an expected meaning or not is unrelated to its grammatical correctness. All the sentences present in my reply are grammatically correct. *Qu'est-ce que le  Tiers-État ?* is definitely a question.

Comment: Đorđe No problem. No reason to apologize, learning a foreign language is tricky...

Comment: I only said that it's incorrect grammar (so it's related to the grammatical correctness). " Qu'est-ce que le cas maintenant ?" is not grammatically correct, because the construction "Qu'est-ce que + noun" is used for defining. and the "maintenant" seems to mean that you expect it as an equivalent for "quel", which it's not.

Comment: @Quidam It is not incorrect grammar. E.g.: [Qu'est-ce que la guerre aujourd'hui ?](https://www.franceculture.fr/emissions/la-grande-table-2eme-partie/quest-ce-que-la-guerre-aujourdhui)

Comment: It means that you definite what is the war, with a modern acception. If you were to use it as a "quel", not with a definition meaning, it would be incorrect grammar. You won't use "Qu'est-ce que la guerre maintenant". That would be incorrect. You can't also make "maintenant" and "aujourd'hui" interchangeable. So you sentence is very different from the one using "maintenant".

Comment: The only case where "Qu'est-ce que la guerre maintenant" is correct, is if you mean that the definition for war changed, (because an even happened for instance, changing its definition). You cannot substitute "maintenant" and "aujourd'hui" anyway, so if "aujourd'hui is correct, because it doesn't change the fact that you define something, substituting another word with another usage and definition doesn't make the first one correct.

Comment: @Quidam You stubbornly refuse to distinguish grammar and opinion. This discussion is pointless. Giving up.

Comment: @Fólkvangr Je l'ai écrit noir sur blanc au début de ma réponse.

Answer (score 0):

**I** 
The problem is purely one of context and of confusion between the meaning of "quel" and the interrogative locution "qu'est-ce que" (considered to be a pronoun in French grammar today); both forms are perfectly idiomatic; the first will fit a common context, the second will be rare as the context it entails is rare for the word "case", and so we are not used to hear it or read it.

The first question is asking which element among a certain more or less known number of elements is the one that is relevant.

> (TLFi) [Quel, adj. interr. + subst. interroge sur l'identité, rarement sur la qualité]

- — Quel est le cas maintenant?

  — C'est le cas que l'on a traité hier.
    — C'est le nominatif.

The second question is asking what is the nature of a certain element named by a word of which, in fact, the meaning is what is being asked.

- — Qu'est-ce que le cas maintenant ?
  — Le cas maintenant c'est ce que ça a toujours été, le nom de la fonction grammaticale du nom dans la phrase, rien de neuf. **(1)**

We can notice that numerous nouns commute with "cas" naturally when "maintenant" is removed.

- Qu'est-ce que le Web ?
- Qu'est-ce que la télévision ?
- Qu'est-ce que la course à pied ?
  …

Adding "maintenant" restricts the context enormously, wherefrom the apparent unnaturalness. However, the special instance of the pupil that believes that the name "cas" in the context of latin grammar could have more than one meaning as his/her "maintenant" points to a possibly new acceptation (**(1)**), makes it unmistakable that the form is idiomatic.

**II** Could we use the second sentence to render the exact same meaning carried by the second one?

If we consider the commutation examined above we see that this is never the case. Would the addition of an adverbial change that ("maintenant")? I think it wouldn't, I see no possibility of that.